# MP3 player for running

Tags: mp3-player

I am looking for an MP3 player for running.

**Must have**:

- display (rudimentary is fine, but no button-only operation)
- shuffle play (random selection for playback)

**Nice to have**:

- runner friendly

  - light weight
  - easy to hold, or small, with a clip, strongly prefer wrist wearable
  - show elapsed running time
- Bluetooth (a bonus would be the ability to turn off BT when using wired 'phones, to conserve the battery); BT should not preclude use of wired 'phones
- some built in memory (even 1GB would be enough; although I could live with micro SD card only)
- playlists (so that I can have one fast-tempo list for running, plus one for all music, maybe one for audio books; note: I do not mind having two copies of a song on the device if I want it in two playlists)
- somewhat rugged (meaning reasonably drop & scratch proof, not military grade - not adding too much to size/weight/price)

**Bonus features**:

- built in pedometer
- auto-detect when running starts & stops
- report calories burned (based on pedometer - which I can already get from Garmin)
- good battery life
- supports MP3, FLAC, Ogg Vorbis, etc
- possibly Spotify support? (I only found one & (a) no display (b) expensive)
- good software for managing it (although I can live with just copying files to/from Windows)

I don't care either way about radio or viewing movies on a pokey little screen. If they don't add to the cost, I can ignore them. Any other runner friendly features that I have missed would be a bonus, as would a personal recommendation of a device that you use.

All else being equal, I will go for the cheapest :-) and would prefer something under 35 EUR / GBP £30 / USD $37

Comment: I have a MP3 player that my sisters are currently using, here's [the link](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Mini-Portable-Bluetooth-MP3-Music-Player-MP4-Media-FM-Radio-Hi-Fi-Lossless-Sound/143372937712?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649) if you wanna check it out (I own the bluetooth one). I will do a review about this product and how it meets some of your requirements. As you can imagine MP3 players are going out of business because of smartphones. Alternatively a used iPod nano could do the job?

Comment: As for runner-friendly, your Garmin should do the job as those cheap players won't do anything else than playing music. There are watches that have microSD slots to play music from them too but I don't think that is what you need (or asking about)

Comment: Interesting. I see that you can now get a Garmin watch with GPS and MP3 for about $200. That's less  that I paid for my Forerunner 225, but it is still like new, so I will continue to look for  a reasonably priced MP3 player to accompany it. Thanks for pointing out the possibility  (+1)

Comment: See [Best running watches with music: MP3, offline Spotify from Garmin and more](https://www.wareable.com/running/the-best-fitness-watches-with-music-playback), [23 Best running watches with Music & GPS (phone-free music) – 2020](https://makelifeclick.com/best-running-watches-with-music-phone-free/) and more